# Generic Method With Generic Return Type

Tags: c#

Suppose there is a generic class like ObjectParameter ; this class extends the IParameter Interface.
So we have something like this: (ObjectParameter is generic class).

```
public class ObjectParameter<T> : IParameter
{
    private T ParameterValue;
    private string ParameterType;
    private string FieldName;

    public void SetValue(T _value)
    {
        ParameterValue = _value;
    }
    public void SetParameterType(string _type)
    {
        ParameterType = _type;
    }

    public void SetFieldName(string _fieldName)
    {
        FieldName = _fieldName;
    }

    public T GetValue()
    {
        return (T)(object)ParameterValue;
    }

    public string GetParamterType()
    {
        return ParameterType;
    }

    public string  GetFieldName()
    {
        return FieldName;
    }

}
```

And the Interface is implemented here:

```
public interface IParameter
{
    string GetParamterType();

}
```

There is a method which Creates ObjectParameter like below:

```
private ObjectParameter<T> CreateParameter<T>(T paramValue, string paramType, string fieldName)
{
    var param = new ObjectParameter<T>();
    param.SetValue(paramValue);
    param.SetParameterType(paramType);
    param.SetFieldName(fieldName);
    return param;
}
```

Now suppose we put ObjectParameters created with method above in a list of IParamter:

```
var parametersList =new List<IParameter>();
foreach (var p in s.Parameters)
{
// p.Value is Sprite,string,int,...
 var _scriptParamter = CreateParameter(p.Value, p.Type, p.MappingAttribute);
 parametersList.Add(_scriptParamter);
}
```

after that we will use parametersList like below:

```
foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{

    var param= parameter as ObjectParameter<Sprite>;
    var fieldName = param.GetFieldName();
    var type = param.GetParamterType();
    var value = param.GetValue();
}
```

or maybe get object parameter as string:

```
foreach (var parameter in parameters)
{

    var param= parameter as ObjectParameter<string>;
    var fieldName = param.GetFieldName();
    var type = param.GetParamterType();
    var value = param.GetValue();
}
```

Now the question is :
How can I combine this two lines in a function:

```
var param= parameter as ObjectParameter<string>;
var param= parameter as ObjectParameter<Sprite>;
```

I have tried this:

```
private ObjectParameter<T> Cast<T> (IParameter t)
{
    if (t.GetParamterType() == "Sprite") return (ObjectParameter<T>)Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(ObjectParameter<Sprite>));
    if (t.GetParamterType() == "String") return (ObjectParameter<T>)Convert.ChangeType(t, typeof(ObjectParameter<string>));
}
```

But it is not working. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you `return t as ObjectParameter<T>`?

Comment: Not possible. I don't see any way of you creating a "Generic cast method". It does even make any sense. Only cast when you  know you need to work with the specified Object

Comment: It isn't possible, as previously mentioned. But why would you want to do that anyways? I suppose that this is why you have created an interface. Expose the methods that are common in the IParameter interface and use it instead.